# NullPointerException in spring boot main method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to set a session value when running the main application. I tried the following way:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Autowired
public HttpServletRequest request;

@Autowired
private CountryService countryService;

private static Class<WebApplication> applicationClass = WebApplication.class;

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

public void set_session_country(){
    request.getSession().setAttribute("session_countries", countryService.getAllCountry());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebApplication webApplication = new WebApplication();
    webApplication.set_session_country();
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

when running application, occurred NullPointerException

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.paid.webapp.WebApplication.set_session_country
>       at com.paid.webapp.WebApplication.main

Comment: can you include a bit more of the stacktrace? the npe is probably originated from countryService

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher , Bro it't not. It's a different question

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis, Bro countryService return list of country

Comment: well it has to be wired to return it. Is it wired? can you provide a bit more of your stacktrace and how the countryService is setup ? Asking about npe looks like you are learning about dependency injection of spring so you may have done that part wrong

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis, okey I use this `request.getSession().setAttribute("session_countries", "hello");` there not use any dependency, just a String,,, but same execption occourred.

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors . NPE shows in the stacktrace ( Which i am asking and you are not providing ) the exact line that they were produced.

Comment: @talex, Dear are you understand my question ???

Comment: @NurHossen you didn't asked any question, so I had to guess.

Comment: Unfortunately the question has been closed... the real answer: you start the application as a regular java application (“main” thread visible in the exception) and try to access the httpservlet request without having an http request. Therefore you get an NPE. I recommend that you try to understand the fundamental model of spring boot AND how servlets work before further experiments.